# Feedparser - TypeError('a float is required',)

Tags: python, lxml, feedparser, libuv

I am using `guv` and `feedparser` to parse multiple feeds simultaneously. The following is my code:

```
guv.monkey_patch(time=True, socket=True)

def parse_feed(_feed):  
    return feedparser.parse(_feed)

def main():
    urls = ["http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml"]
    pool = guv.GreenPool()
    results = pool.starmap(parse_feed, zip(urls))
    for resp in results:
        print(str(resp))
```

However, I get the following output:

```
{'bozo_exception': TypeError('a float is required',), 'bozo': 1, 'feed': {}, 'entries': []}
```

I have the similar problem using `Eventlet`, but not with native Python 3 `threading` library.

Comment: The `bozo_exception` error is returned by `feedparser.parse()`.  If you modify `parse_feed` to print the value of `_feed` before calling `feedparser.parse`, is it receiving what you think it's receiving?

Comment: @larsks thanks. yes, it prints the url from the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to install the `guv` module locally, so I can't test your code verbatim, but if I use `eventlet.greenpool.GreenPool` instead everything works fine:

```
import feedparser
import eventlet.greenpool

def parse_feed(_feed):  
    print 'PARSE:', _feed
    return feedparser.parse(_feed)

def main():
    urls = ["http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml"]
    pool = eventlet.greenpool.GreenPool()
    results = pool.starmap(parse_feed, zip(urls))
    for resp in results:
        print resp

main()
```

I also see correct behavior with `itertools.starmap()`.  Is it possible you're seeing some sort of transient error?